# Rearrange conditionnaly convergent sequence so the partial sums form a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, conditional-convergence

I was reading about conditional convergence vs absolute convergence. I understand from [the wikipedia on Riemann series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem#cite_note-1) how we construct a permutation such that the partial sum converges to any real or to infinity. I also read [this post that sais that there is a rearrangement](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1795604/340973) for which the partial sums are dense in $\mathbb{R}$. But how exactly do we construct the rearrangement?

Comment: Roughly speaking, first enumerate all open intervals in $\mathbb R$ with rational endpoints as $I_1,$ $I_2,$ $I_3,\; \ldots$ Then rearrange terms so that the sum of the first $N_1$ many terms belongs to $I_1,$ the sum of the first $N_2$ many terms to belongs to $I_2,$ the sum of the first $N_3$ many terms to belongs to $I_3, \; \ldots$ where $N_1 \leq N_2 \leq N_3 \leq \ldots$ To get this to happen you may need the $N_k$'s to increase extremely rapidly (e.g. $N_{k+1} > 10^{10^{N_k}}$ or some such) so that when considering the $(k+1)$'st partial sum **(continued)**

Comment: the effect of the first $N_k$ many terms is totally inconsequential. Note that once this is done, you'll have the sequence of partial sums "visiting" each $I_k$ infinitely often (because each $I_k$ contains infinitely many subintervals having rational endpoints), and at this point you can show that each extended real number (not just a dense set of such numbers) is the limit of some subsequence of partial sums.

Answer (score 1):

First, a classical lemma: if a sequence $(u_k)$ has subsequential limits $a < b$ and $\lim_{k \to + \infty} (u_{k+1} - u_k) = 0$, then any points in $[a,b]$ is also a subsequential limit. Now, note that if we denote the series by $\sum_{k \geq 1} a_k$, then $a_k \to 0$ since the series is convergent, and therefore, it is easy to see that for any bijection $\varphi : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, we have
$$
\lim_{k \to + \infty} a_{\varphi(k) = 0}.
$$
Therefore, it suffices to construct a rearrangement whose partial sums have limsup $+ \infty$ and liminf $- \infty$.

To do this, take some upper bound $M$ for $(|a_n|)$ (possible since it tends to $0$ so is bounded). The fact that a series $\sum_{n \geq 1} a_n$ is conditionally convergent implies that
$$
\sum_{i \geq 1} a_{n_i} = + \infty, \quad \sum_{i \geq 1} a_{m_i} = - \infty,
$$
where $(n_i)$ (resp. $(m_i)$) are the indices corresponding to the positive (resp. strictly negative) terms. We can therefore find $i_1$ such that 
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{i_1} a_{n_i} \in [1,1+M],
$$
and we let $\varphi(i) = n_i$ for $i \in \{1, \dots, i_1\}$. Then, we can find $i_2$ such that 
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{i_2} a_{m_i} \in [-2M-3, -M-3],
$$
and we let $\varphi(i_1+i) = m_i$ for $i \in \{1, \dots, i_2\}$. In particular, we have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{i_1} a_{\varphi(i)} > 1, \quad \sum_{i=1}^{i_1+i_2} a_{\varphi(i)} < 1+M - M - 3 = -2.
$$
Continuing, we obtain a permutation $\varphi$ and a sequence $(i_k)$ such that, if we let
$$
S_k = \sum_{i=1}^k a_{\varphi(i)}, \quad j_k = i_1 + \cdots + i_k,
$$
then for every $k \in \{1,2, \dots\}$,
$$
S_{j_{2k-1}} > 2k-1, \quad S_{j_{2k}} < -2k.
$$
In particular,
$$
\limsup_{k \to + \infty} S_k = + \infty,  \quad \liminf_{k \to + \infty} S_k = - \infty,
$$
and we are done.

Comment: Thank you. Are you proving that $\sum_{k\ge 1} a_{\phi(k)}$ has a subsequent limit $a$ $\forall a \in (-\infty,+\infty)$?

Comment: Yes, because of the lemma: its liimsup is $+ \infty$, its liminf is $- \infty$, and $a{\phi(k)} \to 0$, so every value is a limit point. Think of it this way: it can take arbitrarily large values and arbitrarily small ones, and it has to do so by taking very small steps, so it has to get very close to each point in between.

Comment: But in the lemma you ask $\lim_{k\to \infty}u_k=0$ so shouldn't you have here that $\lim_{k\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^k a_{\phi(k)}=0$ rather than just $\lim_{k\to \infty} a_{\phi(k)}=0$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that is a typo, it should be $\lim_{k \to + \infty} u_{k+1} - u_k = 0$, that is, $(u_k)$ takes very small steps.